# Selecting entry which has max value and deleting others for a specified date

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-2.7, datetime

I have such a database structure :

```
CREATE TABLE `tenant_counter` (
    `id`    TEXT,
    `date`  TEXT,
    `time`  TEXT,
    `date_time` TEXT,
    `sayacdeger`    REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id,date_time)
);
```

My applıcatıon stores 24 sayacdegers for each id every day. And what i need to do is after collecting all those sayacdegers , after 23:00 at the end of day, to keep entry which has max value of sayacdeger and delete others for that day. For this purpose, I wrote :

```
def sadelestir():

    threading.Timer(3600, sadelestir).start()

    sadelestirme_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    if (sadelestirme_time.hour<23):
        return

    print "Sayaclari sadelestiriyor"

    # Connecting to the database file
    conn2 = sqlite3.connect('tenantdata.sqlite')
    c2 = conn2.cursor()

    c2.execute('''delete r
    from tenant_counter r left join
         (select date, max(sayacdeger) as maxvalue
          from tenant_counter
          group by date
         ) rn
         on r.date = rn.date and r.sayacdeger = rn.maxvalue
    where rn.date is null''')

    conn2.commit()
    conn2.close()
    return
```

When i run this code,i get syntax error:

```
    where rn.date is null''')
OperationalError: near "r": syntax error
```

I never dived into sql this much before. So i cant figure out the problem. I ll apprecıate much your help.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Python.

The error most likely comes from the first line of the SQL statement, you should not put anything between delete and from. See [SQLite DELETE syntax](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html)

Even so, you have at least two more errors.

First, you cannot use join in the DELETE. You can rewrite that with IN or EXISTS (See [Deleting value using SQlite while doing an INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709405/deleting-value-using-sqlite-while-doing-an-inner-join))

Second, you're joining on r.id = r.maxvalue; it doesn't make any sense to join the id with the max of sayacdeger.

The solution should be something like this:

```
DELETE FROM tenant_counter
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tenant_counter AS r
WHERE r.id = tenant_counter.id AND r.date = tenant_counter.date 
AND r.sayacdeger > tenant_counter.sayacdeger)
```

This will delete all for which there is at least one record for the same id and date with a larger sayacdeger. It will keep duplicates if you have the same maximum value in more than one record. You need to decide on a strategy for that case, whether you want that or you want to keep only one record.

Note: I didn't test the above SQL statement.

Comment: Serban, Thats cool. Yes , i did not know how to convert that sql query to sqlite. That was the real problem. And i noticed , in your query, ı cant see the part about how to do that operatıon only for current date. I ll try but i would appreciate your help also

Comment: c2.execute('''DELETE FROM tenant_counter
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tenant_counter AS r
WHERE r.id = tenant_counter.id AND r.date = '{xn}' 
AND r.sayacdeger > tenant_counter.sayacdeger)'''.\
           format(xn=today))

Comment: That query solves keepıng only maximum values for each entry. And as you mentioned before, It keeps duplicates for the same maximum value in more than one record. So how can we change or another query for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You may find the 'EXISTS' condition useful: (Untested query to give an idea)

```
DELETE
FROM tenant_counter 
WHERE EXISTS
     (SELECT rn.date, MAX(rn.sayacdeger) AS maxvalue
      FROM tenant_counter rn
      WHERE tenant_counter.date = rn.date 
       AND tenant_counter.sayacdeger = rn.maxvalue 
       AND rn.date IS NULL
      GROUP BY rn.date)
```

Comment: delete
        from tenant_counter r left join
             (select date, max(sayacdeger) as maxvalue
              from tenant_counter
              group by date
             ) rn
             on r.date = rn.date and r.sayacdeger = rn.maxvalue
        where (rn.date = '2015-08-15')
                        ''')                                                                           When i run this, i get ( OperationalError: near "r": syntax error )

Comment: @ŞansalBirbaş see above edit to give you an idea to start with.

Comment: I will try. But again there is no date definition in your wuery. Maybe instead of "rn.date is null " it must be "rn.date='2015-08-15'" ?

Comment: @ŞansalBirbaş yes I just copied your query. In fact I might do something like `WHERE rn.date < (select max(date) from tenant_counter group by ID, strftime('%Y-%m-%d', rn.date))`. But that is a guess depending on your table structure. I think that will work with SQLite.